# Shopping car in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I am creating an online shop with laravel 5.3 and I want when the user clicks add product to add it in their shopping cart
I have tried to do it with session in the controller but it gives me Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found error
here's my code
View:

```
<a href="checkout">
     <h3> <div class="total">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>
            @if(Session::has('price'))
                {{ Session::get('price') }}lv

            @else
                0.00lv
            @endif
          </span> (<span id="simpleCart_quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> products)</div>

     </h3>
</a>
```

Routing:

```
Route::get('add-product/{id}', 'ProductsController@add')->name('add-product');
```

ProductsController:

```
public function add($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    if (Session::has('price')) {
        $price = Session::get('price');
        $price += $product->product_price;
        Session::put('price', $price);
    }

    else {
        Session::put('price', $product->product_price);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I don't know if this si the right way to do it but I have no other idea how it's done, if someone can tell the right way i will be more than happy to hear them

Comment: import `session` before using it, like `use Session` or call it from the root namespace `\Session::has('price')`

Comment: The problem was that I've gotted to use Session yeah
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Helper methods ( [`session`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-session) ) to use session class without exporting them like this:

View:

```
<a href="checkout">
     <h3> <div class="total">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>
            @if(session()->has('price'))
                {{ session()->get('price') }}lv

            @else
                0.00lv
            @endif
          </span> (<span id="simpleCart_quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> products)</div>

     </h3>
</a>
```

Controller:

```
public function add($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    if (Session::has('price')) {
        $price = session()->get('price');
        $price += $product->product_price;
        session()->put('price', $price);
    }

    else {
        session()->put('price', $product->product_price);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check out [This amazing package](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart) very good to implement. I have used it [on this shopping cart.](http://www.wakodeals.com) successfully